# D3 circle pack: html in text attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, circle-pack

The code below works fine in that I can output a text string into the bubbles.

But how do I output HTML markup into the bubble text label? You can see my HTML markup in the first "name" attribute.

This div is very simple in this example, but it will eventually contain more markup and a class id to a css

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var json = {
            "name": "flare",
            "children": [
                { "name": "<div>test1<br>test again</div>", "size": 20, "color": "#ff0000" , "id": 1},
                { "name": "test2", "size": 40, "color": "#ffff00", "id": 2},
                { "name": "test3", "size": 60, "color": "#ff0000", "id": 3},
                { "name": "test4", "size": 80, "color": "#ff00ff", "id": 4 },
                { "name": "test5", "size": 100, "color": "#0000ff", "id": 5}
            ]
        };

        var r = 400,
            format = d3.format(",d"),
            fill = d3.scale.category20c();

        var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
            .sort(null)
            .size([r, r])
            .padding(1.5);

        var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", r)
            .attr("height", r)
            .attr("class", "bubble");

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(bubble.nodes(classes(json))
            .filter(function (d) { return !d.children; }))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color; })
            .on("click", function (d) { alert("id: " + d.id); });

        node.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", "0.3em")
            .text(function (d) { return d.dispText.substring(0, d.r / 3); });

        function classes(root) {
            var classes = [];

        function recurse(name, node) {
            if (node.children)
                node.children.forEach(function (child) {
                    recurse(node.name, child);
                });
            else
                classes.push({
                    packageName: name, dispText: node.name, value: node.size, color: node.color, id: node.id});
            }

            recurse(null, root);
            return { children: classes };
        }

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the `foreignObject` tag, which allows you to embed HTML (or other XML namespaces) - Mike Bostock has a good example of using this here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037

In your case, this might look like (untested):

```
node.append("foreignObject")
    // I believe w/h are required, though the size is arbitrary
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 50)
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .html(function (d) { return d.dispText.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, I've got a lot of positioning/styling to do, but this got me going. My first day with D3 and SVG

Comment: Unfortunately foreignObject is not supported in IE 9 & 10

Comment: If you need IE support, the other option is to add HTML elements outside of the SVG, and position them according to the properties in the SVG - this is definitely possible, but can get a bit hairy. See [this method in jQuery.powertip](https://github.com/stevenbenner/jquery-powertip/blob/master/src/placementcalculator.js#L150) for an example of placing HTML elements based on an SVG element.